# Read data from one database and store it in other database

Tags: java, database

I have a local database that contains 10 tables. My work is to read data from each table (select data from each table with some condition) one by one and then store that data in a remote database.

The remote database has the same 10 tables that are in the local database. In a simple way, I have to port data from the local database to the remote database.

How best to do this?

Comment: First of all, what database are you using?...

Comment: for local database i am using firebird and for remote database i am using mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a stored procedure in the local database that does the copying from the local database to the remote database. Call that stored procedure from your Java program.

This is possible only if your database implementation supports linking to remote databases from a different implementation.

Answer (score 2):

If i talk in oracle you can create a db link in the destination DB say source_link

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm

Then connect to the destination DB

insert into A (field1,field2,...) select field1,feild2.... from A@source_link where

Nothing to do with Java but a efficient way too

Answer (score 1):

You can use ETL (Extract/Transfer and Load) . Spoon is a free tool that you can create transformations purely using SQL to perform this type of a task.

http://kettle.pentaho.com/

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Spoon+User+Guide

http://rpbouman.blogspot.com.au/2006/06/pentaho-data-integration-kettle-turns.html

Answer (score 1):

The very basic an simple way to achieve this is to use [jdbc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)

First you need  to connect to each database, for that you need a `jdbc driver` for each database system you have to deal with, jdbc driver is a library implementing the [jdbc API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/package-summary.html) and is provided by each database vendor for his database system.

See [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html) that shows how you can establish a connection to a database.

After you have established a [Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) you can create a [Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) to retrieve and update data. retrieved data is returned in a [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).

[This link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) shows how you can do that.

To summarise, you need to do the following steps

1. Create a `Connection` to source database
2. Create a `Statement` and send your `select` queries to source database
3. retrieve the reulsts using the `Resultset` and save in a collection of some POJO
4. Close the `ResultSet`, the `Statement` and the `Connection` of source database
5. Create a `Connection` to target database
6. Create a `Statement` and send your `update/insert into` queries to target database
7. Close the `ResultSet`, the `Statement` and the `Connection` of target database
8. done!

Comment: "retrieve the reulsts using the Resultset and save in a collection of some POJO " You know any api that do this or i have to traverse the resultset and put that data in pojo?

Comment: @WaqasAli In that case you may want to have a look at the [Java Persistence API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html). You'll have then to deal with [Entities](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html) and [EntityMangers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html). For `JPA` all the work is done under the hood like I described in the sptes above.